# Uniform distribution of dots on world map depending on latitude

Tags: python, coordinate-system, cartography

I would like to plot a map looking something like this:

[image]

I'd like to then connect each dot with the corresponding country and use it to display statistics. Therefore I need a set of coordinates, ideally calculated in python based on actual coordinates.

However, I want the dots to be uniformly distributed and I don't really know how to achieve that.
What kind of projection could I use? Is this even possible?

I tried a basic algorithm with a lot of "if" statements, which adjusts distance between two points based on the latitude, but the result is far from uniform. Basic code example:

```
def generate_lat(resolution):
    lat = 0
    lats = [lat]

    while lat < 90:
        if abs(lat) >= 80:
            step = resolution / 5
        elif abs(lat) >= 70:
            step = resolution / 4
        elif abs(lat) >= 50:
            step = resolution / 2.5
        elif abs(lat) >= 45:
            step = resolution / 1.5
        elif abs(lat) >= 30:
            step = resolution / 1.3
        else:
            step = resolution

        lat = lat + step if lat + step < 90 else 90
        lats.extend([lat, -lat])

    return sorted(lats)


def generate_coordinates(resolution):
    longitude_range = arange(-180, 180 + resolution, resolution)
    points = []
    latitudes = generate_lat(resolution)

    for lat_ind, lat in enumerate(latitudes):
        for lon in longitude_range:
            # offset every other line
            if lat_ind % 2:
                lon = lon + resolution / 2
            points.append((lat, lon))
save_file(points, resolution)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add a code snippet with the python code that you used?

Comment: @karpfen I added the code

Comment: Are the statistics area-based? If so, an equal are projection like Sinusoidal might be better.

Comment: ... or any other projection from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area .